# Subform Linking Issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I built a report that uses a sub report and am experiencing an unusual error.

I create the sub report within my main report and set up the "Link Master Fields" and "Link Child Field" properties using the field "[OpportunityID]". The record sources of both reports have this field available and work correctly independently. After creating the sub report within the main and switching from design view to Report View I get the expected result and the report works great. I can close the main report, open it back up at any time, and it continues working great.

HOWEVER if I close the database, re-open it, and then try to open the main report I get the pop-up "Enter Parameter Value" dialog box for the [OpportunityID] field. I get this pop-up once for each record in the main report. By blasting through the pop-ups clicking "OK" or "Cancel" the report finally opens but the link is now broken because I get no records in the sub report. I can fix the issue by flipping to Design View, wiping out the subreport entirely, and then re-linking it. Again the report will work as intended for so long as I keep the database open. As soon as I close the database and re-open, the links are broken again.

This is very frustrating and appears to be an MS Access software bug. Does anyone know how I can get around this problem??

Comment: Please post the record source of the main and sub-report

Comment: Is there any code behind the reports? Are there any calculated fields/controls on the reports?

Comment: Never experienced this so can't agree this is a bug. Might have to examine the db to analyze issue.

Comment: Have you tried compact and repair?

Comment: @jhalf2008: Have you ever tried to give feedback? ;-)